# How to use SQLite fts MATCH queries in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

i've got a SQLite database with a table "books"

sqlalchemy is set up so i can query the database like this:

```
Session.query(Book).filter(Book.title.like(u'%linux%')).all()
```

since the table is a virtual table that support fts4 (http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_3) we can search for **whole words** like this

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE title MATCH 'linux';
```

and for whole words **in all columns** like this:

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE books MATCH 'linux';
```

using sqlalchemy this requires "literal sql" (http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/tutorial.html#using-literal-sql) since the books column does not exist

```
Session.query(Book).filter(Book.books.match(u'linux')).all()
*** AttributeError: type object 'Book' has no attribute 'books'

Session.query(Book).filter('books match :text').params(text=u'linux').all()
```

in sqlite we also can search for books with title 'linux' and 'driver' in any of the other columns:

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE books MATCH 'title:linux driver';
```

via sqlalchemy this should work somehow like that::

```
Session.query(Book).filter('books MATCH title:title :text').params(title='linux', text='driver').all()
```

unfortunately this leads to an error:

```
*** OperationalError: (OperationalError) near ":title": syntax error u'SELECT ...\nFROM books \nWHERE books MATCH title:title ?' ('driver',)
```

i tried to escape the colon using `title\::title` or `title:::title` but could not succeed.

using sqlalchemy 0.7

Comment: http://runnable.com/Ur8myPOxx4hmAARP/using-full-text-search-with-python-and-sqlite-for-tutorial-beginner-sqlite3-fts-database-query-and-fts4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MATCH expects a single string.

If you have multiple strings you must concatentate them.
In SQL, this would look like this:

```sql
... WHERE books MATCH 'title:' || 'linux' || ' ' || 'driver'
```

In SQLAlchemy, this should be written like this:

```py
...filter("books MATCH 'title:' || :title || ' ' || :text").params(...)
```